# PHP snag when using strange quotes

Tags: php, quotes

Copying a mySQL-driven application and its web-pages (in PHP) I spent 2 days of time debugging the problem exemplified by code below. The 2 "didn't work" comment of course do not apply to the source server (where everything works OK) but do apply to the destination server where nothing works!
The web pages make use indiscriminately a mixture of single (hex 27), double (hex 22) and "funny" (hex e2 80 99).

What can I do? "sed'ing" every page would be easy but what about next time when
I have to re-migrate again these pages?

Thank you very much!

```
<?php

  echo "Welcome to a quote adventure<BR><HR>";

  $_SESSION['number1']=1;
  $_SESSION['number2']=2;
  $_SESSION['number3']=3;

  echo "my number1 (single-to-single quotes) is: ".$_SESSION['number1']."<BR>";
  echo "my number2 (single-to-double quotes) is: ".$_SESSION["number2"]."<BR>";
  echo "my number3 (single-to-funny quotes) is: ".$_SESSION[’number3’]."-------didn't work!<HR>";
 
  $_SESSION["number1"]=1;
  $_SESSION["number2"]=2;
  $_SESSION["number3"]=3;

  echo "my number1 (double-to-single quotes) is: ".$_SESSION['number1']."<BR>";
  echo "my number2 (double-to-double quotes) is: ".$_SESSION["number2"]."<BR>";
  echo "my number3 (double-to-funny quotes) is: ".$_SESSION[’number3’]."-------didn't work!<HR>";
 
  $_SESSION[’number1’]=1;
  $_SESSION[’number2’]=2;
  $_SESSION[’number3’]=3;

  echo "my number1 (funny-to-single quotes) is: ".$_SESSION['number1']."<BR>";
  echo "my number2 (funny-to-double quotes) is: ".$_SESSION["number2"]."<BR>";
  echo "my number3 (funny-to-funny quotes) is: ".$_SESSION[’number3’]."-------worked!<HR>";
?>
```

I was expecting the web pages to work unmodified also on the destination server

Comment: How are you copying the mysql databases?  Please provide more info.

Comment: Basically, "strange quotes" **do not** have any meaning an **any** PHP version. You have to get rid of them once for all. They DO NOT "work" in any sensible meaning.

Comment: Also, as a programmer, you are supposed to **pay attention to error messages** PHP emits, when it runs your code. Which are quite self-explanatory in your case.

Comment: What kind of process are you using to copy files that inserts typographic quotes? Pasting them in Microsoft Word?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I suppose these quotes could be already present in the code and it even would "work" in the older PHP versions, although spitting warnings right and left

Comment: redwards: the problem is in PHP: I posted a piece of code having nothing to do with any database, and it behaves differently on different servers.

Comment: Your Common Sense: running the php through apache you do not see errors or warning. So I run in PHP directly and I saw them. They appear equally well on the original server where all works. But you are right when you say that I should take them away.

Comment: Sounds like the silent machine has error messages silenced in PHP.

Comment: Of course `$_SESSION['number3']=3;`or `$_SESSION["number3"]=3;` and then `echo $_SESSION[’number3’];` won't work - `'number3'` and `"number3"` are text literals with the value `number3`, whereas `’number3’` is an _undefined constant_, and ignoring that it is not defined, PHP will assume you meant the _value_ `’number3’` here. So these are _different_ array keys.

Comment: As pointed out, the right answer was to point my attention to error messages: this pushed me first to run a part of the code in PHP (where they were immedaitely apparent) and next to look for these errors in the apache logfile. Examining the errors finally

Comment: (hate the return ending and publishing comment)
Since warnings about strange accents appeared equally well in the (working) 
server machines, I went deeper and deeper and found that the not-working
server did not work for an entirely unrelated point.
That I fixed, and now the transition to the new server is completed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you've changed servers and didn't review PHP settings thoroughly, it's very likely that you're relying on defaults that have changed, in particular the ones related to [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). Your code was never fully correct, it worked partially by pure chance, but you've only realised now.

PHP has been hardening some error conditions because they were a source of frustrating bugs and didn't really serve any purpose. In particular, reading from a non-existing constant has been promoted from notice to warning:

1. Early PHP: assume you missed quotes and actually wanted a string, trigger notice.
2. PHP/7.2: same assumption, trigger warning.
3. PHP/8.0: no more guessing, trigger fatal error.

... key difference being that fatal errors abort the script, thus cannot be easily missed or ignored.

How does this non-existing constant issue apply here? Well, turns out that `’` is a valid identifier for constants, as long as you don't use it in a location where the parser chokes:

```
define('’a’', 'example');
$foo = ['example' => 'OK'];
var_dump(’a’, $foo[’a’]);
```

```
string(7) "example"
string(2) "OK"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oHvKe)